# Loading library (rgdal) on windows?

Tags: r, proj, rgdal

I just started in the R field. I installed R project and then R studio.

I want to execute a process with library (water) and I need before calling RGDAL and I get the following error:

```
library("rgdal", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.4")
rgdal: version: 1.2-8, (SVN revision 663)
 Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
 Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15
 Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/MaGregor/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rgdal/gdal
 Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 492]
 Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/MaGregor/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/rgdal/proj
 Linking to sp version: 1.2-5
```

Comment: That doesn't read like an error, more an information message. Does rgdal refuse to work?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not an error.

Comment: Soy nuevo usando este programa. Disculpen si digo que "es un error" y no lo sea.

Answer (score 1):

Library(water) [depends on the rgdal library, along with raster and sp](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/water/index.html). Those three go hand in hand for importing and exporting spatial data and managing it within R. When you execute `library(water)` for the first time in any R session, those dependent packages will always be loaded as well. Some packages do this without fanfare, others post a little announcement to your console when they're loaded. Rgdal is one of the wordier ones. Its not an error.

Make sure you have all your dependencies installed - I can see you have rgdal and sp, but I can't tell if you have raster.

Comment: Gracias por la pronta respuesta, en realidad sí, primero cargo library(sp), luego library(raster) y luego library(rgdal) y ahí sale ese error.